# app hangs for some time when navigate in different screens

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

i am working on an app which contains 21 screens at all, when i navigate to other screens, back buttons or other buttons stucks for a little time. 
i am using swreavelViewController, if go to other screen via segue, and if click back button it stucks app for a moment.. i have uibuttons and or other items, it stucks the app.[image]

i am not using navigation controller, i go to other screens via segues,

Comment: are you doing heavy loading on view will appear ?

Comment: a collectionView is being reload that have 21 values...

Comment: yes that reload makes the view choppy. move the reloading to the viewdidload. dont do any heavy operation in viewWillAppear. if you must to reload then have some 2-3 sec delay. then reload. that may be your quickfix

Comment: Thanks Karthik for this guide, but i not using viewWillAppear, doing all stuff in viewDidLoad..

Comment: id your view deinit called ?

Comment: Dear karithik, i am very greatfull of your time, but issue is, app is just loaded, collectionView have reloaded, and i want to open swReveal side menu, menu button does not work often, some time it works... some time is does not..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188073/discussion-between-user2478881-and-karthik).

Comment: use dismiss viewcontroller on back button, because when you use segue on back button, you just create new view controller, which is wrong and your app not going to work fine.

Comment: swreavelViewController last update 4 years ago. Why you use it? Write you own side menu

Comment: wow... write a new library, ok i will  , for this time can you suggest any other library like swreavelView... please